# Where to read about this kind of "measure of irredundancy" of a set from a family of sets?

Tags: reference-request, st.statistics, measure-theory, applications, applied-mathematics

Studying a very practical problem from psychometrics, I encountered the following construction.

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space; if preferred, you can presume $\mu$ is a probability measure. In any case it is better to assume that $\mu(X)<\infty$.

Given a finite collection $\mathscr X=\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ of measurable subsets of $X$, I want to define on them some sort of "irredundancy measure" $\mu_{\mathscr X}$, telling "how much each $X_i$ contributes in catching information not provided by the rest".

At the zeroth stage, all $X_i$ are on equal footing, $\mu_{\mathscr X}^{(0)}(X_i)\equiv1$. The first refinement of this I want to take is
$$
\mu_{\mathscr X}^{(1)}(X_i):=\sum_j\mu(X_i\setminus X_j);
$$
the meaning - "$X_i$ is the more irredundant the more it covers something not covered by the others in the collection".

The second refinement will have the same meaning but will weigh each $X_j$ in the sum according to the first approximation. That is, covering some ground not covered by $X_j$ is the more valuable the more $X_j$ itself is irredundant. Indeed, if $X_i$ covers something not covered by some $X_j$ which itself is redundant, this should not mean much. So,
$$
\mu_{\mathscr X}^{(2)}(X_i):=\sum_j\mu(X_i\setminus X_j)\mu_{\mathscr X}^{(1)}(X_j)=\sum_{j,k}\mu(X_i\setminus X_j)\mu(X_j\setminus X_k).
$$

It is now clear how to proceed, one just iterates this further. Alternatively, one may formulate the procedure as follows: form the square matrix $M$ with $M_{ij}=\mu(X_i\setminus X_j)$. Then the vectors $\mu_{\mathscr X}^{(k)}$, $k\geqslant0$ are given by $s$, $Ms$, $MMs$, $MMMs$,... where $s$ is the vector $(1,...,1)$.

My final outcome now is either the whole sequence of these $\mu_{\mathscr X}^{(k)}$, or maybe just only their sum, i. e. $(1-M)^{-1}s$ (provided $1-M$ is nonsingular). Also the eigenvectors of $(1-M)^{-1}$, or vectors from the null space of $M$ might be relevant.

And the question is -

> Does anyone know some similar construction? Or maybe a hint in which area/topic to look for it? What might be search keywords? Are there more sophisticated approaches to measuring irredundancy known? What should be the "infinitary" version of this? That is, when $\mathscr X$ is some measurable subset of $X\times I$ where $I$ itself is a measure space more complicated than $\{1,...,n\}$?